# Install pyarrow on ARM

Tags: arm

I am not able to install pyarrow on ARM processor using the instructions found here...

https://gist.github.com/heavyinfo/04e1326bb9bed9cecb19c2d603c8d521

I am getting this error:

```
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ubuntu/arrow-apache-arrow-0.15.1/cpp/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ubuntu/arrow-apache-arrow-0.15.1/cpp/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

Is there any easy way to install pyarrow on ARM?

Comment: I am using EC2 instance (Ubuntu) and not able to install pyarrow.

Comment: Could you please share the contents of `/home/ubuntu/arrow-apache-arrow-0.15.1/cpp/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log` and `/home/ubuntu/arrow-apache-arrow-0.15.1/cpp/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log`?

Comment: There are negative comments under your link for the kind of problems that you're also encountering. Try instead the [arrow2-graviton2](https://gist.github.com/eladroz/b9437249a76de2b394d54e646d53ec5e) instructions.

Comment: Those instructions are for Amazon Linux. But I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly the standard commands mentioned on official site works for ARM processor even if it is not mentioned anywhere!

https://arrow.apache.org/install/

Comment: These did not work for me. pip install bombs out due to VS